# Claymation with real eyes

Tags: identify-this-movie, animation, short-films

I remember seeing a stop-motion animated short film a year or two ago on the Internet (I think either YouTube or Vimeo). The most memorable thing about it was that the characters were animated but had real eyes superimposed on them (similar to 'syncro-vox').

Other details:

- Little to no talking
- Was made sometime after 2000, most likely just a few years ago
- Took place mostly on a train
- Set in 20's or 30's (the protagonist wore a cloche)
- I think it might have been French or Canadian
- A ghost or other mystical element might have been involved

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like the Oscar-nominated short [Madame Tutli-Putli](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1029440/combined) from 2007.

> Madame Tutli-Putli boards the Night Train, weighed down with all her earthly possessions and the ghosts of her past. She travels alone, facing both the kindness and menace of strangers. As day descends into dark, she finds herself caught up in a desperate metaphysical adventure. Adrift between real and imagined worlds, Madame Tutli-Putli confronts her demons and is drawn into an undertow of mystery and suspense.

It's silent claymation, happens in the 20s (or at least looks it) and has human eyes superimposed over the characters. Here it is:

Comment: Its probably a positive match, but that ain't no 20's steam engine!